# How to make "/home" partition after installation completed in Fedora 18?

Tags: fedora, partition

I've installed Fedora 18 Spherical Cow with the new installer and I created 3 partitions from free space on the hard drive (`/`, `/boot` and swap).

After I completed the installation, I figured out that there is 8G still free and I want to use it for a `/home` partition.

Is that possible now? How I do it?

Hard drive:

- primary partition (for windows system) NTFS
- logical partition ( for data ) NTFS
- `/boot` partition (ext4)
- LVM Volum group :
  [ -Fedora-root partition (ext4)&
  Fedora-Swap partition ]

And 8G free space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cfdisk as root to create a partition in the free space. Provided the new partition is named, say, sda5, you have to create a filesystem on it with the
mkfs family of commands: 'mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda5' will work if you choose ext4. As for mounting, mount it on a temporary mountpoint, copy all your files from the present /home there, mount sda5 to /home, copy back, make it a permanent mount point by editing /etc/fstab and reboot. :)

Comment: But better do the last steps after logging in as root, perhaps in a console (or just boot appending 1 to the kernel boot line)

Comment: But the root partition and Swap are included in LVM group how i will include /Home to LVM group

Comment: You never bothered to tell us that in the question. Please explain in detail what your exact disk setup is.

Comment: Sorry i thought when i mentioned ' installation in fedora 18 ' automatically will know that fedora new installer use LVM group in his automatic partitioning . well when i installed fedora at first time it was like that but no home partition 
http://www.linuxbsdos.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/FedoraDualWindows10-600x450.png

Comment: You don't have to include /home in the LVM group. The above advice would suit you even if the rest of the partitions are in a LVM group.

Comment: OK i already create new partition using the free space only problem i didn't know how to make the mount point permanent by editing fstab file, did i just open the file and change him ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You can take the other mount points as examples.